# Does the browser load files in media stylesheet when not required?

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

I just want to know if the browser loads or skips these external css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />
```

If the screen is more than 800px width, and if it load the file, what can i do for avoid it? I don't want that the browser loads files that the user will not need.

Comment: Browser loads it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ## The browser will load all specified `<link>`'s.

This is done on the server-side, whereas rendering the appropriate content is done on the client-side.

You can see exactley what has been loaded in your browsers developer tools <kbd>F12</kbd>, under sources.

---

If your worried about loading multiple big stylesheets, there are several options.

1. Put the majority of your styles in a single shared stylesheet, then just have smaller ones for the different-sized screens, as there shouldn't be that much change between the two.
2. Dynamically load the appropriate styles using JavaScript once the page has loaded. See [this link](https://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/#article-header-id-1) on exactly how to do that - it's Farley easy.

---

For reference, this article about [Different Stylesheets for different devices](https://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/) is worth a read on CSS Tricks